# Php Mysql Updates

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a database where a user can enter any number of interests. When they go to update it they can remove one of their former interests.

How should this be handled? Should an update delete all their former interests from the database and then insert their updated ones?

Comment: When you say 'check off' do you mean 'remove'?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your table design and provide an example of a user and their possible interests and the changes they would like to make to their interests.

Comment: As long as you will never need to track 'Entry Date', 'Removal Date' for these 'interests', then your approach is ok.   If you might want to track that type of information in the near future, might as well set it up for that now (remove only the ones that no longer apply, add in any new ones).

Comment: @ Nathaniel Ford yes that is what I mean "remove"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I usually do: Delete all the existing records and add the new ones. It's the simplest thing to do if it's a simple cross reference table. If there are id fields that are important you might have to do something else.

Comment: Thanks. No id fields important. Just wanted to make sure it was a logical way of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

If your pool of interests are not stored in a separate table, you can use the flag approach:

Users Table (example)

```
user_id int(8) AUTO_INCREMENT
user_name varchar(255)
user_email varchar(255)
```

User Interests table (example)

```
interest_name varchar(255)
user_id int(8)
interest_status tinyint(1)
```

The interest status could be a 1 (for active interest) or a 0 (for former interest)

On the flip side, if you have a pool of interests too choose from and a binary association table, then change the `interest_name` to the `interst_id` it represents. Delete all the old records and reinsert them with the problem flags. It's usually the easier thing to do and is less error prone.